# How do charges arrange themselves at electrostatic equilibrum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

How do charges on conductors re-arrange themselves when they are placed next to other conductors? I understand how charges arrange themselves on the surface of conductors but I can't find an explanation for this question.

Let's assume we have three identical conductive thin plates placed at distance d apart. A charge 2q is deposited in the leftmost plate and -q on the other two. After electrostatic equilibrium is established, what is the charge on each face of the plates? Sorry I don't have a better way to find an explanation. I've calculated the field in each region but how do they affect the charges?

Comment: Read ampere's circuital law carefully. I hope this will help you (Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J. Griffths).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it is a similar process. By definitions of electrostatic equilibrium and conductor, the charges will end up (at electrostatic equilibrium) in such a way so that the electric field within each conducting plate is 0.

There seems to be a common homework problem where you consider a conducting shell nested in another conducting shell of smaller radius. Then, you place a charge at the center of the whole system (inside both nested shells) and consider what the charge distributions look like on each shell. This question might help give insight into your particular problem since it (the concentric shells) seems to be a simplified version of your problem.

Perhaps consider looking at this stack post on the concentric shells problem: [Potential of Concentric Shells](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284572/potential-of-concentric-shells).

Comment: I have read the post and understand how induction works in two charged objects. I do not understand how it works for more than two objects though.